# Swift NSUserDefaults NSArray using objectForKey

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults

I'm pretty new to Swift, and I've managed to get pretty stuck.

I'm trying to retrieve data from `NSUserDefaults` and store it in an array (`tasks`):

```
@lazy var tasks: NSArray = {
    let def = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    let obj: AnyObject? = def.objectForKey("tasks")
    return obj as NSArray
}()
```

All I'm getting is a warning: `EXE_BAD_INSTRUCTION` on line 3.

Also to note that I haven't actually set any data yet, but what I'm aiming for is that if there is no data, I want the array to be empty. I'll be using the data to populate a table view.

Now using a var instead of a constant:

```
@lazy var tasks: NSArray = {
    let def = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    var obj: AnyObject? = {
        return def.objectForKey("tasks")
    }()
    return obj as NSArray
}()
```

The error has now moved to the return line.

Comment: I'm not sure you can assign nil to a constant. What happens if you replace `let obj` with `var obj`?

Comment: I tried using a var, I get the same warning now on the return line (updated).

Comment: Add an exclamation mark to the return type? `NSArray!`.

Comment: That seems to have helped, however the warning has shifted: http://cl.ly/WQEK

Comment: @LordZsolt why exclamation mark? Since `objectForKey` may return nil, the property type should be optional, i.e. end with a question mark `?`.

Comment: @kambala Yeah, but in that case it should be returning an empty array, not nil, as far as I've understood his question.

Comment: Yeah I need an empty array, not nil. Also: http://cl.ly/WQF9

Comment: try `return tasks?.count;`. If it also crashes, then you have to actually return `NSArray.array` from the property in case `objectForKey` returns `nil`

Comment: Preinitialise `obj` to be an empty array: `var obj: AnyObject[] = []`.

Comment: I couldn't get either of those to work. This works, but it's ugly: http://cl.ly/WQKy

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the problem here is that you are attempting to cast `nil` to a non-optional type and return it. Swift does not allow that. The best way to solve this would be the following:

```
@lazy tasks: NSArray = {
    let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    if let array = defaults.arrayForKey("tasks") as? NSArray {
        return array
    }
    return NSArray()
}
```

Using Swift's `if let` syntax combined with the `as?` operator lets you assign and safe cast in one line. Since your method does not return an optional, you must return a valid value if that cast fails.

Comment: This pretty much works (I think). I had to change `arrayForKey` to `objectForKey` as I had an error: `'NSArray' is not a subtype of 'AnyObject[]'`.

Comment: Cool yeah I wasn't sure if that was on purpose. Swift Array <-> NSArray bridging still seems to have problems occasionally.

Comment: This is not working for me... 

I copied the code right into my Project and it won't work