# 'String' is not identical to 'AnyObject' error

Tags: ios, swift, nsarray, nsuserdefaults, watchkit

I'm having issues when trying to pass data to my Apple Watch app through NSUserDefaults from my app. Whenever I try to retrieve the array that is stored, I am getting the error `'String' is not identical to 'AnyObject'`.

I've been trying to figure out a solution but I can't work out what the issue is since I am using the same method elsewhere in my app and it works without issue.

Here is what I have in the Apple Watch part:

```
    var defaults = NSUserDefaults(suiteName: "group.AffordIt")
    tempNames = defaults?.objectForKey("namesWatch") as NSArray
    tempDates = defaults?.objectForKey("datesWatch") as NSArray
    tempAmounts = defaults?.objectForKey("valuesWatch") as NSArray
```

And the containing app part:

```
    defaults?.setObject(names, forKey: "namesWatch")
    defaults?.setObject(dates, forKey: "datesWatch")
    defaults?.setObject(values, forKey: "valuesWatch")
```

names, dates and values are String arrays.

Any ideas?

Comment: When this happens to me, its because I incorrectly used ?. to chain the optional when I really meant !. - I'm not in front of my Mac, but I would try that

Comment: Are you sure you haven't accidentally set a string instead of an array at some point during your execution?

Answer (score 0):

IMO your problem is, that you try to cast an optional value, e.g.

```
if let names = defaults.objectForKey("namesWatch") as? NSArray
{
    tempNames = names
}
```

Probably this SO question is related: [Swift NSUserDefaults NSArray using objectForKey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24598991/swift-nsuserdefaults-nsarray-using-objectforkey).

Comment: No, because `as NSArray` unwraps the Optional.

Comment: Yes. Sorry, was confused by the OPs cast to `NSArray` without giving information, that he wants to write `[ String ]` although that should have been clear to me...

Answer (score 0):

```
let namesStringArray = ["John","Mary"]
let datesStringArray = ["May 21, 2009, 11:10 PM"]
let doublesStringArray = ["1.5","2.2","3.3"]

if let defaults = NSUserDefaults(suiteName: "group.AffordIt") {
    defaults.setObject(namesStringArray , forKey: "namesWatch")
    defaults.setObject(datesStringArray, forKey: "datesWatch")
    defaults.setObject(doublesStringArray, forKey: "valuesWatch")
}
let defaults = NSUserDefaults(suiteName: "group.AffordIt")
if let tempNames   = defaults!.stringArrayForKey("namesWatch") {
    println(tempNames)  // ["John", "Mary"]
}
if let tempDates   = defaults!.stringArrayForKey("datesWatch") {
    println(tempDates)  // ["May 21, 2009, 11:10 PM"]
}
if let tempAmounts = defaults!.stringArrayForKey("valuesWatch") {
    println(tempAmounts)  // ["1.5", "2.2", "3.3"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast the objects you are retrieving from your collection as being Strings:

```
defaults?.setObject(names, forKey: "namesWatch") as? String
defaults?.setObject(dates, forKey: "datesWatch") as? String
defaults?.setObject(values, forKey: "valuesWatch") as? String
```

Comment: No problem with receiving a down vote, but if there is an error in this answer please do point it out so both the OP and I can get the benefit of the information. :)